# Why do I get an error when I try to use redirect in Nextjs ( SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am learning NextJS, and I am trying to build an easy recipe app. I am using the new App Router, and everything worked well until the login function. So basically when I login, and it is successful (I'm using Prisma and MongoDB and I just looking if there is already an user with the same username in the database), I get the same error over and over again when I try to redirect to the homepage. I tried it without NextReponse.redirect() where I basically just returned a NextResponse saying Login is successful. Then it worked. So my question is why can I not redirect to the homepage after I logged in successfully?
This is the error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

route.ts file which is in src/app/api/user/login

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "../../../../utils/prisma";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { username, password } = body;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      username,
    },
  });
  if (!user) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "User " + username + " not found" },
      { status: 404 }
    );
  }
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!match) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Password incorrect" }, { status: 303 });
  }
  NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
}
```

page.ts file in src/app/auth

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function LoginRegister() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center gap-40 text-2xl mt-40">
      <Login />
      <Register />
    </div>
  );
}

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  async function loginHandler() {
    const data = { username: username, password: password };
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  }

  return (
    <form className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label
          className="block text-gray-900 font-bold mb-2"
          htmlFor="username"
        >
          Username
        </label>
        <input
          className="shadow border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          id="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setUsername(e.target.value);
          }}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label
          className="block text-gray-900 font-bold mb-2"
          htmlFor="password"
        >
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          className="shadow rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 mb-3 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="******************"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setPassword(e.target.value);
          }}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="button"
          onClick={loginHandler}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

So I tried NextResponse.redirect just redirect and it is always the same error as I have mentioned before. I thought that i could just return to my homepage after i logged in but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things working against you here:

1.) Fetch won't redirect to a different page. You'll have to manually handle it.

2.) You're not always returning a json response, therefore invoking `res.json()` throws an uncaught error:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((res) => res.json()) // uncaught error because the response may be a redirect which isn't valid JSON (it's undefined)
```

What you probably want is a client-side "redirect" (or this case, replace `/login` with `/`).

Example server endpoint:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type ResponseData = {
    error: string
}

export default function handler(
    _req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
    // swap this for checking username and password
    if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials." });
    }

    /*
       I'd highly recommend using a more semantic response to a valid
       login event -- like a 200 response -- instead of a redirect:
       res.status(200).end();
    */

    res.redirect(307, "/");
}
```

login.tsx page

```
import type { FormEvent } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            setError("");
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            });

            // if the response is 400+, then expect a json response
            if (!res.ok) {
                const data = await res.json();
                throw Error(`Unable to login, reason: ${data.error}`);
            }

            // otherwise, this will replace the "/login" history page with "/"
            // and navigate the user to "/"
            router.replace("/");
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error?.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <main
            className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24"
        >
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                <div className="mb-4">
                    <label
                        className="block text-gray-900 font-bold mb-2"
                        htmlFor="username"
                    >
                        Username
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className="shadow border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        id="username"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setUsername(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label
                        className="block text-gray-900 font-bold mb-2"
                        htmlFor="password"
                    >
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className="shadow rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 mb-3 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        id="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="******************"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setPassword(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <button
                        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                {error && <p className="text-red-800 font-bold">{error}</p>}
            </form>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything works fine.